# jquery selector-accessing anchor from with table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to access the `anchor` tag in my `jquery` nested as follows. I want to select each anchor and add a click event to it in `jquery`.

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
    <th>Tags</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Batch ID</th>
    <th>Source</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Details
        <div id="detailsdiv">
         <a href="#" id="default">Default</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
         <a href="#" id="wrap">Wrap</a>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>Account Name</th>
    <th>Col15</th>
    <th>Col16</th>
    <th>Col17</th>
    <th>Col18</th>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

Select the anchor tags using the following:

```
$("table #detailsdiv a")
```

And apply the click functionality using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$("table #detailsdiv a").on("click", function() {
    //use this to select the element that has been clicked
    $(this);        

    //Do click functionality here
});
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) jQuery method directly:

```
 $("table #detailsdiv a").click(function() {
     //use this to select the element that has been clicked
     $(this);         

     //Do click functionality here
 });
```

Comment: I have two anhor i want to access both

Comment: That selector will apply your click functionality to both anchor tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#detailsdiv a').click(function(event){

    // Cancel the default action (navigation) of the click.
    event.preventDefault();

    // You can get the id of clicked link
    alert(this.id);

    // Your code goes here..
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  $("#detailsdiv a").click(function() {
            // add function  And
            $(this) // add function for clicked tag
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr th a').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //your function here;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can also try this:

```
$('table  #detailsdiv a').click(function(e){
    alert(this.id);
});
```